# JMeter: Why page keeps on loading continuously while recording using Proxy

Tags: https, proxy, load, jmeter, protocols

I am trying to record a scenario where, after login, user clicks on a button that takes user to a page which has graphical data.

But just after Login and on click of button, the page keeps on loading continuously, however, manually it responds very fast.

I have confirmed security exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of any unexpected behaviour the first place you should take a look at is *jmeter.log* file - it normally contains enough troubleshooting information to figure out the cause.

You can increase log verbosity for the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (located under JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
log_level.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy=DEBUG
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Few other tips:

1. Try [clearing your browser history](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000510.htm) (including cache)
2. [Re-install JMeter dummy certificate](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
3. If nothing helps - there is an alternative option of recording a JMeter test via [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)